# Send Clojure 'doc' output through pager?

Tags: clojure

The docstrings for some Clojure functions (e.g. `defrecord`) are quite long.  When running Clojure at in a terminal window, I'd like to be able to in effect send `doc`'s output through a pager such as `more` (or `less`).  If someone has written a pager function in Clojure, then I think I could use it along with something like:

```
(with-out-str (doc defrecord))
```

Or if there is a standard Java class that implements a pager, I can figure out how to send the output to that.

Alternatively, how can I send the output of `doc` to a shell command? This doesn't do the job:

```
(clojure.java.shell/sh "more" :in (with-out-str (doc defrecord))))
```

[This topic is difficult to search: "more", "less", and "doc" are obviously very common terms, and things like "java pager" bring up pages discussing ways to break text up into pages for formatting documents.]

Comment: Why not just write a program that prints the doc then pipe that to more?

Comment: `echo "(doc defrecord)" |clj|more`

Comment: spinning up a full jvm clojure instance each time you want a doc string seems a bit extreme

Comment: @DiegoBasch's solution is OK.  I just didn't think of it.  I keep a minimal version of clojure in my path.  On a faster machine, the delay isn't obtrusive.  On a slow machine, well, if I'm going to take all of the time to page through the docs, it's not so bad to wait for it to fire up.  But a solution like Jared314's jline setting would be better--though I *did* want to do it from inside a lein repl.  Here's a script, which I'll call `cloman`:  #!/bin/sh
echo "(doc $1)" | clojure | less

Comment: @DiegoBasch, if you make your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.  (Jared314's answer is also very helpful.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "(doc defrecord)" |clj|more
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jline](https://github.com/jline/jline2) for this. If you call `setPaginationEnabled`, with `true`, and use the [`printColumns`](https://github.com/jline/jline2/blob/master/src/main/java/jline/console/ConsoleReader.java#L3508) method, on your jline [`ConsoleReader`](https://github.com/jline/jline2/blob/master/src/main/java/jline/console/ConsoleReader.java), it will page.

But, if you are trying to do this at a standard Leiningen REPL, things get more complicated. The current version of Leiningen v2 uses [REPL-y](https://github.com/trptcolin/reply/), which uses jline internally, but doesn't use `printColumns`, so the jline pagination is ignored.

You can, however, get the current Leiningen REPL height through REPL-y's ConsoleReader, in `reply.reader.simple-jline/jline-state`, and use it to partition the doc string.

```
(defmacro doc2 [x]
  `(let [h# (-> @reply.reader.simple-jline/jline-state :reader (.. getTerminal getHeight) (- 4))
         [s1# s2#] (split-at h# (-> ~x clojure.repl/doc with-out-str clojure.string/split-lines))]
     (doseq [x# s1#] (println x#))
     (doseq [i# (partition-all h# s2#)]
       (println "\n<more>")
       (read-line)
       (doseq [x# i#] (println x#)))))
```

You would want to put this macro in your `profiles.clj` under the `:repl` profile.

```
{:user {:plugins [...]}
 :repl {:repl-options {:init (defmacro doc2 [x] ...)}}}
```

This would put the `doc2` macro in the `user` namespace when you load the repl.

Comment: If you use this, just a heads-up that `reply.reader.simple-jline/jline-state` is implementation-specific and likely to break in future REPLy versions. Another implementation-specific (and likely to break) solution is here: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/1199#issuecomment-18815789